# Flutter Admob's widget get error when setState is call

Tags: flutter, set, admob, state

I have a problem with Admob's widgets.
I am developing a new feature for a flutter app that contains an Admob banner widget.
But when I setState the value of another widget, the Admob Widget gets an error.

I am using :`google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0+1`

The banner is build like so:

```dart
      @override
      void initState() {
        setState(() {
          _adBanner = createBannerAd();
        });
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        _adBanner.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
```

And the widget is display like this:

```dart
    Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: myPercent(2, screenHeight)),
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _adBanner.load(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                  width: myPercent(95, screenWidth),
                  height: myPercent(6, screenHeight),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: AdWidget(
                    ad: _adBanner,
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Container();
            }),
```

The log error catch :

```
    flutter: click
    flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building AdWidget(dirty, state: _AdWidgetState#a1afb):
flutter: This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree
flutter: If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder function
flutter: with a unique ad object.
flutter: Make sure you are not using the same ad object in more than one AdWidget.
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   AdWidget file:///Users/sofian/Work/Personal/Mobile/WhatUDo/what_u_do/lib/views/idea.dart:295:34
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      _AdWidgetState.build (package:google_mobile_ads/src/ad_containers.dart:372:7)
flutter: #1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4825:27)
flutter: #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4708:15)
flutter: #3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4880:11)
flutter: #4      BuildOwner._runWithCurrentBuildTarget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2708:15)
flutter: #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4407:12)
flutter: #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4687:5)
flutter: #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4871:11)
flutter: #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4682:5)
flutter: ...     Normal element mounting (10 frames)
flutter: #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3660:14)
flutter: #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3422:20)
flutter: #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4733:16)
flutter: #21     BuildOwner._runWithCurrentBuildTarget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2708:15)
flutter: #22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4407:12)
flutter: #23     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4789:5)
flutter: #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
flutter: #25     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4733:16)
flutter: #26     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4880:11)
flutter: #27     BuildOwner._runWithCurrentBuildTarget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2708:15)
flutter: #28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4407:12)
flutter: #29     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2813:33)
flutter: #30     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:899:21)
flutter: #31     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:320:5)
flutter: #32     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1119:15)
flutter: #33     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1057:9)
flutter: #34     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:973:5)
flutter: #38     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:157:10)
flutter: #39     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:253:5)
flutter: #40     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:120:31)
flutter: (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add error logs? seems like some info there but can't able to read on gif..

Comment: Could you pls link which of the ads packages you use? there's a bunch on pub.dev (https://pub.dev/packages?q=admob)

Comment: I am also getting same error message.

Comment: hey, hi. could you fix this problem? i got same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69412225/added-admob-and-now-getting-spammed-with-audiomanager-logs and ant find any solution neither here nor anywhere else. if you did can you please tell a little bit? because this problem is the last step of my app before publish!!

Answer (score 3):

According to the google ads package example

[googleads-mobile-flutter](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/main/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/lib/reusable_inline_example.dart)

You have to use didChangeDependencies

```
  class BannarAdWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   const BannarAdWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<BannarAdWidget> createState() => _BannarAdWidgetState();
  }

  class _BannarAdWidgetState extends State<BannarAdWidget> {
   BannerAd? _bannerAd;
   bool _bannerAdIsLoaded = false;

   @override
   void didChangeDependencies() {
   // Create the ad objects and load ads.
   _bannerAd = BannerAd(
    size: AdSize.banner,
    request: const AdRequest(),
    adUnitId: AdmobHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
    listener: BannerAdListener(
      onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
        print('$BannerAd loaded.');
        setState(() => _bannerAdIsLoaded = true);
      },
      onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
        print('$BannerAd failedToLoad: $error');
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('$BannerAd onAdOpened.'),
      onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('$BannerAd onAdClosed.'),
    ),
    )..load();

   super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
   _bannerAd?.dispose();
   super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final BannerAd? bannerAd = _bannerAd;
   if (_bannerAdIsLoaded && bannerAd != null) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
      width: bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
      child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd),
    );
   } else {
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
   }
  }



  class AdmobHelper {
    static String get bannerAdUnitId {
     if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
     } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
     } else {
      throw UnsupportedError('Unsupported platform');
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: nice find, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

As from question and error log, seems like you are trying to fresh screen/widget using `setState` but not the actual ad based container widget - still you are getting this error.

If I understood correctly.. then issue is about ad widget is trying to rebuild on `setState` call with older ad object but it expect new ad object everytime new build. So, avoid those kind of widget build if that's not required.

create a seprate ad based container widget like `AppXyzAdWidget` and move the ad's parent container code and other ad related code inside the new widget and use the newly created ad based widget on your screen.

This way you can decouple your screen without ad related things then after `setState` will not reload your ad and their widget just only refresh your content.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState()` causes the widget to rebuild, so your `FutureBuilder()` widget fires the future task again. This is why you're seeing this error.

You need to remove `FutureBuilder()` and move your future task to `initState()`:

```
// ...
// Some code

@override
void initState() {
  setState(() {
    _adBanner = createBannerAd();
  });

  _adBanner.load().whenComplete(() {
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _showAdBanner = true;
      });
    }
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _adBanner.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

// ...
// Some code
```

You can also have boolean to make the `AdWidget()` appear when the future task is complete:

```
bool _showAdBanner = false;

// ...
// Some code

_showAdBanner
  ? Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
  width: myPercent(95, screenWidth),
  height: myPercent(6, screenHeight),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: AdWidget(
    ad: _adBanner,
  ),
)
  : Container()

// ...
// Some code
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you remove initState code and initialize _adBanner in your build function like this ?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _adBanner = createBannerAd();
    return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: myPercent(2, screenHeight)),
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _adBanner.load(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
              width: myPercent(95, screenWidth),
              height: myPercent(6, screenHeight),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: AdWidget(
                ad: _adBanner,
              ),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
```

Comment: Don't put any loading thing inside the build method

Comment: @NimrSawafta _adBanner.load() is a future and is inside FutuerBuilder. What is wrong with loading a future in a FutureBuilder ?

Comment: Yes it is and each time you called the AdWidget, which is a Future by itself, and for your code, each time you call the build method it will rebuild the ad, and case a drop in frames, and possible suspend from google.

Comment: @NimrSawafta The error says => "This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree flutter: If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder function flutter: with a unique ad object". So it was necessary to load the ad every time to fix the problem. However the admob package has been updated already with handling of this issue.