# Flutter:- This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
 void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    bannerAd = BannerAd(
        size: AdSize.banner,
        adUnitId: AdMobService.bannerAdUnitId,
        listener: BannerAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (_) {
            setState(() {
              _bstatus = true;
            });
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
            print("failed to load banner$err");
            ad.dispose();
          },
        ),
        request: new AdRequest());
    bannerAd.load();
  }  

// code where it causes error

 bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Stack(
            children:[
              Text("Ad  space"),
               if (_bstatus)
                AdWidget(
                ad: bannerAd,
                key: UniqueKey(),
              ),
              ]

          ))
```

This is my code _bstatus is to check if banner is loaded or not.
On starting an app it works fine but when ads get reload it give the below error

```
The following assertion was thrown building AdWidget-[#06603](dirty, state: _AdWidgetState#c9e02):
This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree
If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder function
with a unique ad object.
Make sure you are not using the same ad object in more than one AdWidget.
```

But if I do hot reload it works fine

How could I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Those, who still facing the issue, should use the below code as a solution.

1. Create a separate File.
2. Just Call the widget Tile in your ListView and pass `PubId` (Provided by Admob) to it.

> Make Sure to create a separate file for the code

```
class AdMobWidgetTile extends StatefulWidget {
          const AdMobWidgetTile({required this.adId, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
          final String adId;
          @override
          State<AdMobWidgetTile> createState() => _AdMobWidgetTileState();
        }
        
        class _AdMobWidgetTileState extends State<AdMobWidgetTile> {
          BannerAd? bAd;
          String id=UC.getRandom;//Any Random String
          @override
          void initState() {
            // TODO: implement initState
            super.initState();
            BannerAd(
                size: AdSize(
                  height: 250,
                  width: 320,
                ),
            
            adUnitId:widget.adId,
            listener: BannerAdListener(
                onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {},
                onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
                  log("BANNER AD FAILED:");
                  ad.dispose();
                },
                onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
                  setState(() {
                    bAd =ad as BannerAd;
                  });
                  log("BANNER AD LOADED:");
                },
                onAdOpened: (Ad ad) {}),
            request: AdRequest())..load();
      }
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return
          bAd!=null?
          Container(height: 250,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5,),
            child: AdWidget(
                  ad: bAd!,
                  key:Key(id) ,
                ),
          ):20.x;
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // TODO: implement dispose
        super.dispose();
        bAd?.dispose();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be a duplicate of the following question:

[Flutter :- This AdWidget is already in the Widget tree. How to disable this exception. And what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899247/flutter-this-adwidget-is-already-in-the-widget-tree-how-to-disable-this-exce)

The error is quite explicit, did you make sure to provide an unique ID ?

Comment: how can i assign unique id ? ,Isn't it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are putting the same widget again and again. You can fix this by creating a new stateful class and returning the Adwidget. This will build that same widget multiple time—it works like a Builder. This solved my problem; I hope it will work for you too.